# Understanding tutorial from the official website

Tags: mithril.js

I'm very new to Mithril and trying to understand the tutorial from the official website. I've modified the example a little bit. Here's the version without `m.request`. The snippet below doesn't render anything on the page. It's as if the change detection(?) is not triggered after an async action. How would you make it work? Thank you!

```js
const User = {
    list: [],
    loadList(){
      //new code starts
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function(){
          User.list.push({name: 'Foo'}, {name: 'Bar'});
          resolve();
        }, 1000);
      })
      //new code ends

      /* original code
       return m.request({
         method: "GET",
         url: "https://rem-rest-api.herokuapp.com/api/users",
         withCredentials: true,
       })
      .then(function(result) {
         User.list = result.data
       })
      */
    }
}
const UserList = {
  oninit: User.loadList,
  view(){
    return m(".user-list", User.list.map((user) => {
     return m(".user-list-item", user.name)
   }))
  }
}

m.mount(document.body, UserList)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mithril/1.1.1/mithril.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Auto-redraw function isn't triggered after `setTimeout`. One have to trigger it manually with `m.redraw()`.
More information can be found in the [docs](https://mithril.js.org/autoredraw.html#when-mithril-does-not-redraw)

Comment: Beat me to it, glad you found the info you needed!